# why angular proxy not working in wampserver

Tags: angular, proxy

I have a problem with my angular 7 app in wampserver

I made this

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  }

"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

my application returns this to me

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost/api
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 286
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:08:40 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) PHP/7.2.10

Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/vdfrontend/
```

I used an htacces file within the directory of the project and also modify the virtual host file

htaccess file has the next information

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

the virtual host file has the next information

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/vdfrontend"

    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/vdfrontend">
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html
        # to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my application returns this to me again

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost/api
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 286
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:08:40 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) PHP/7.2.10

Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/vdfrontend/
```

my app not works due this, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your Angular server and the Apache (WAMP) HTTP server you're proxying to are both on localhost, correct?  Apache is on port 80, and Angular is on port 4200, correct?  What's on port 3000?

Comment: The api is in localhost listening by the port 3000, the api is running in node.js, I use express. I deployed the angular 7 application in wampserver I used this command ng build --prod --baseHref=/vdfrontend --deployUrl=vdfrontend/. I'm not using the port 4200 because I deployed the angular 7 application in wampserver. I have to solve this issue because I need to pass the two applications to production, the application server that is the api and the angular 7 application. Tell me if is necessary to answer another question to solver this issue I will response as soon as posible. Regards

Comment: Got it.  So you copied Angular "/dist" (here, "/vdfrontend") to Apache, and you're running your proxy on NodeJS port 3000.  Cool - that's all fine.  So the 404 is definitely coming from Angular.  Q: Does `ng serve --proxy-config...` (no Apache) work?  SUGGESTION: Set your Angular log level to "Trace" and connect to your app (http://localhost:4200") with Chrome Developer tools.  Also look [here](https://dzone.com/articles/note-to-self-debugging-angular-4-routing): `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }) ],`

Comment: yes ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json work fine when the application angular 7 is not deployed on apache I use npm start

Comment: outside apache the two applications work perfect

Comment: In my angular 7 application

In my service file I have this

API_URI='/api';

tha package.json has this

"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

and the proxy.conf.json has this

{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  }

Comment: my problem is when I deployed the angular 7 application in wampserver, I puted in the browser localhost/vdfrontend (I used this command ng build --prod --baseHref=/vdfrontend --deployUrl=vdfrontend/ to deploy in production I copied the folder vdfrontend that is in dist) and I have problem in the console web, I'm going to publish the image of this problem

Comment: Tracing/logging is your friend.  1) Enable tracing on your RouterModule, 2) Set 'Trace' loglevel in your app, 3) Use Chrome Developer Tools/F12 on your browser.  You want [console] and [network] tabs. 4) Look at the trace output in your Apache logs.  Post back what you find.

Comment: ok I'm going to do what you said thanks, I published the images of the problem

Comment: I posted what I finded

Comment: You said your "api" is running on port 3000.  But your trace shows "somebody" (your browser running the Angular app?) is doing a `GET http://localhost/api`, port 80.  Hence the HTTP 404 error!

Comment: Q: Did you get things working?  If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It probably wasn't a good idea to add three new responses - it would have been better just to put your additional information in the original post :(

ANYWAY:

You said your "api" is running on port 3000.  But your trace shows "somebody" (your browser running the Angular app?) is doing a `GET http://localhost/api`, port 80.

Hence the HTTP 404 error!

POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS:

1. Forget about the proxy, forget about NodeJS - just deploy your API on the WAMP/Apache server.  That should resolve the problem - everything will be on port 80.
2. Alternatively, consider serving both Angular and your API on NodeJS (and forget about WAMP, and forget about the proxy).
3. If you really want two servers (both WAMP and NodeJS) in production, you should consider CORS:

   [How to handle CORS in an Angular2 and Node/Express Applications](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/how-to-handle-cors-in-an-angular2-and-node-express-applications-eb3de412abef)
4. One other link you might find helpful:

   [Building a REST-Backend for Angular with Node.js & Express](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express)

'Hope that helps .. PSM

---

You *MAY* configure Apache as a reverse proxy for your Node API server if you really, really want to.  The problem is that it's not working.  Your Angular app is trying to connect to "api" on port 80; it's actually on port 3000.  Yet another complication is that Apache is "picky" about names: perhaps it should be"/api/" instead of "/api" (for example, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757340/apache-proxy-config-conflicting-with-angular-routing)).

My suggestions were to simplify your configuration by moving everything over to one or the other server, eliminating the need for the proxy, and eliminating any potential cross-domain Javascript issues.

Here are a couple of additional links that might help:

- [How to get Apache and Node working together on the same domain with Proxied Javascript AJAX requests](https://blog.cloudboost.io/get-apache-and-node-working-together-on-the-same-domain-with-javascript-ajax-requests-39db51959b79)
- [Setup reverse-proxy for API calls for your Angular application with Node.js backend on a Nginx server](https://medium.com/@spencerfeng/setup-reverse-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-application-with-node-js-62321f0defb5) (uses Nginx instead of Apache, but the concepts are similar).

Comment: a friend told me that I have to configure apache to reverse proxy